# The result set has no current row while using JDBC

Tags: database

I am using the following code in selenium, but I am not able to retrieve data from database. I am getting the errors **"The result set has no current row"**

My code is

```
public class Auto {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {


        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded");


        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.*****\\SQLEXPRESS/*****_DW/EPS:****;user=******;password=******; ");

        System.out.println("Driver loadedd");


    java.sql.Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from [*****_DW].[dbo].dim_grantee ");

    System.out.println("Query executed");

    while (rs.next());
    {
        String Name=rs.getString("NAME");

        System.out.println("Name is");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while (rs.next());
{
    String Name=rs.getString("NAME");

    System.out.println("Name is");
}
```

to

```
while (rs.next())
{
    String Name=rs.getString("NAME");
    System.out.println("Name is");
}
```

i.e. remove semicolon from `while` line

Answer (score 0):

**The short version**: Your query is not returning any rows.

**The long version**: You need to find out *why* your query is not returning any rows. The first step is to either step through the code with a debugger, or add a lot of print statements to determine what exactly is going on.

I suspect that either the table is empty or the connection is not properly formed. You might want to look at the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-the-result-set-has-no-current-row) for more information.

Comment: Why does `rs.next()` return true in that case?

Comment: We don't know from the description whether the error is being thrown on `rs.next()` or not. My assumption was that the error was being thrown by the `rs.next()` check.

Comment: Kate, Connection is proper because for metdata it is working fine i can get the number of column count and all...that means connection is correct...